# How to delete an edit in Final Cut Pro (un-blade)

Tags: final-cut-pro

> I want to be able to "undo" the blade tool, in effect merging clips
>   together. How can I do this?

*(Answered [another](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/3937/how-to-delete-an-edit-in-final-cut-pro-un-blade/3939#3939) question without noticing it was for Final Cut X, not FCP 7, but here is the answer for anyone using Final Cut Pro 7)*

Comment: No, I didn't look at your other answer :-)

Comment: haha, beat me to the punch :p

Comment: I did. Being an FCP fan, I couldn't pass up the question. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have made an edit and you want to remove it, you can **click on the edit** then **press <kbd>delete</kbd>** and the edit will be removed.

fig1. selected edit:

[image: Selected edit in Final Cut 7]

*Note that this only works if the time on either side of the edit hasnt changed, as indicated by the red triangles.* If you have cut out any video, you cant delete the edit:

[image: Indicator]

Answer (score 0):

You can just select the edit and hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>. If you removed any video in between, you won't be able to delete the edit.

Answer (score -1):

Click on the line for the edit that you have done with the blade in order to select it and then press back space.